# JS code works fine within html file ,but when place it in external file it return Uncaught ReferenceError: Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function that show/Hide the password field when needed :

```
 function showP() {
    var x = document.getElementById("passw");
    if (x.type === "password") {
      x.type = "text";
    } else {
      x.type = "password";
    }
  }
```

and place it in external js file and called from within the html page:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

and this is the part in the html page where it is called:

```
Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" required id="passw">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="showP()">
```

when the function is placed inside the html page in script tag it works fine , but when called from external file it return :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showP is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick

so where it the problem ?

Regards

Comment: Probably the URL doesn't point to the JS file. Debug it with the Network tab in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: thanks for the reply , it just worked , no idea how or why ?! maybe after refreshing the entire site , could this be it ? although i refreshed the page containing the script previously .